# TOAD ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Tags: sql, database, oracle, export, toad

I was trying to export huge data to excel files on Toad.

I changed the 
**Toad Options -> Oracle -> General -> Max Varray Size** tab. After then any query did not work. I can not select even a few columns.

I added the screenshot. Please could you help me?

[image: Screenshot of Toad]

Comment: I am not sure that `Max Varray Size` is the problem here ... but for what it's worth - my setting is `100` for that field.

Comment: My setting is 100 too. When I tried to change, it shows an error popup and then seems again empty. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in trouble with Toad and couldn't find any solution to use it then I found this solution:

*Utilities -> Copy User Settings -> Previous installation(of course if you have) or 
Create a clean set (just i did)*

It works like before.

Thank you.